# Not well-ordered X Axis values

Tags: highcharts

In the attached image,  the values on x axis are not order, it is increasing from 1 to 112 then it decreases from 101 to 0.

I'm asking if there is any way to do the same using Highcharts.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: How does this even work? How does one read one of these? How does the data look (to not be ambiguous)? Under some circumstances you could just edit the label text.

Comment: Or use two separate xAxes - with one with [`reversed`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.reversed) option. Then split data into two and it's ready.

Comment: Thank you, I did that before, but there is no way to  change the position of the second x axis. here is my jsfiddle script: http://jsfiddle.net/7wwpLLzt/1/

Answer (score 1):

Example how could this be done: http://jsfiddle.net/7wwpLLzt/9/

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    xAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        min: 1,
        max: 224,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        maxPadding: 0,
        minPadding: 0,
        tickPositions: [1, 15, 33, 55, 78, 98, 112]
    }, {
        offset: 0,
        min: 1,
        max: 224,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false,
        reversed: true,
        maxPadding: 0,
        minPadding: 0,
        showLastLabel: false,
        tickPositions: [1, 15, 33, 55, 78, 98, 112]
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'S1',
        type: 'spline',
        xAxis: 1,
        data: [
            [13, 7],
            [44, 3],
            [56, 4]
        ],
    }, {
        name: 'S2',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
            [1, 2],
            [14, 3],
            [100, 6]
        ]
    }]
});
```

Used are two axes, one for left and one for right side.

Comment: an other way to do it is formatting x axis labels : http://jsfiddle.net/7wwpLLzt/5/

Comment: Feel free to post your example as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is formatting x axis labels : jsfiddle.net/7wwpLLzt/5

```
xAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                  var maxValue=112.6;  // max value on x 
                if ( this.value > maxValue )
                {
                    return  parseFloat(maxValue - ( this.value - maxValue)).toFixed(1);  
                }
                else
                {
                    return  parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(1);     
                }


            }
        }

    }],
        tooltip: 
      {
        formatter: function () {
            var xa = this.x;
            var maxValue=112.6;  // max value 
            if ( xa >maxValue )
            {
                xa = parseFloat(maxValue - ( xa - maxValue)).toFixed(1);
            }
            var s = '<b>' + xa + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
                    this.y + 'm';
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
```